# Hooks for Links Box

Tags: hooks, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting archive pages in WP's AJAX internal link finder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/getting-archive-pages-in-wps-ajax-internal-link-finder)

Are there any hooks for the new [internal links box](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11420) that was created in [WP 3.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.1)? I'm trying to modify it in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there are no hooks to do that from a plugin and the function that makes the search query itself is not pluggable which means that the only way to achieve that is to hack core files.

Currently there is an [open Trac Ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18042) asking for some kind of hook.